# If $A_{n}$ are disjoint and $P (B\mid A_{n}) \geq c$ for every n, then $P(B\mid \cup A_{n})\geq c$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

how can I prove this:

If $A_{n}$ are disjoint, and $P (B\mid A_{n}) \geq c$ for every n, then $P(B\mid |  \cup A_{n})\geq c$.

Any help guys?

Comment: Does $UA_n$ denote the intersection of $U$ and $A_n$?

Comment: @angryavian I edited. Thanks. It is the union of $A_{n}$

Comment: Do you suspect this exercise was intended to illustrate material you recently covered in class or in a textbook?  Is it similar to an exercise you already saw worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$P(B \mid \bigcup_n A_n) = \frac{P(B \cap \bigcup_n A_n)}{P(\bigcup_n A_n)}
= \frac{\sum_n P(B \mid A_n) P(A_n)}{\sum_n P(A_n)}.$$
Can you finish the rest?

> $$\frac{\sum_n P(B \mid A_n) P(A_n)}{\sum_n P(A_n)} \ge \frac{c \sum_n P(A_n)}{\sum_n P(A_n)} = c.$$

Comment: $\sum_k P A_k \ge P A_n$ for any $n$. Or the convex sum of some numbers is $\ge$ their $\min$.

Comment: Thanks! $P(B|A_{n)}$ is already bigger than c. Right? So I can isolate it and there will be the answer. Am I right?